# msxsl:script for c# in xslt function declared twice error

Tags: c#, xslt

Hey all I'm trying to write an xslt template that uses a msxsl to create a hyperlink from a web.config appSetting. Every time I try to run the code, it tells me that I have declared the c# method in the script twice. The code is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:files="urn:my-script" >
        <msxsl:script implements-prefix="files" language="CSharp">
    <msxsl:assembly name="System.Configuration"/>
    <msxsl:using namespace="System.Configuration"/>
    <![CDATA[
    public string LinkFile()
    {
         string link = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileUrl"];
         return link;
    }
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:template name="GenerateLinkFile">
    <xsl:param name="fileName"/>
    <xsl:param name="fileId"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$fileName = ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$fileName"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <a href="files:LinkFile()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fileName"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error I'm getting is as follows at **runtime** when it tries to generate the hyperlink:
System.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException: Type 'System.Xml.Xsl.CompiledQuery.Script1' already defines a member called 'LinkFile' with the same parameter types.

Comment: Is this definitely the XSLT you are using? It's badly formed; for example, the xsl:stylesheet element is not terminated with a `>`and there is no matching </xsl:stylesheet>. When I add those, your XSLT compiles and runs - which makes me wonder if it's a data issue. Do you have a sample web.config file you are running this on? And what version of .Net are you using, please?

Comment: I forgot to close the two tags, those are included in my code, I can't include the web.config, but the error shows that it's this location in the code (line numbers are the method declaration and the following line). It's not a data issue because it's trying to call the method and thinks there's more than one

Comment: I ran it against a sample XML file and it worked for me which also makes me wonder what version of .Net you are using, and if you are referencing other XSLT templates in your transforms - one of which might have this function declared too?

Comment: I created this from scratch, there are no other places script or otherwise where this function is called. This template is the only one that accesses this script. I'm running .Net 3.5. This template is being called from another .xslt file though; could that really cause this issue?

Comment: @dash You were right, the issue is calling this stylesheet from other multiple xslt files. Make your comment a full response so I can accept

Answer (score 3):

I ran your XSLT against a sample XML file and it ran well; this led me to believe you are probably calling this XSLT multiple times from other XSLT files.

The best way to handle this is that, if you have a root transform calling other transforms, to include it from there, so it is only referenced once; the aim is to ensure that the function is only included once throughout your transforms, otherwise you will encounter the error you are seeing.

Alternatively, call this transformation independently - a common approach is to apply XSLT's to the source document in turn, performing sets of transformations one at a time.